# Are roots of minimal modulus closed under multiplication?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, analytic-number-theory

Given any algebraic number $a\in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, let $f_a(x)$ denote its minimal polynomial.  Let $R_a=\{r\in \mathbb{C}|f_a(r)=0\}$.  The set in question is $$C:=\{a\in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}: |a|\le \min_{r\in R_a}\{|r|\}\}.
$$
Is the set $C$ closed under multiplication?

This is a question concerning my research which is a little outside my area.  Does anyone know if the following problem is already solved?  My intuition(which has been wrong plenty of times before) tells me the answer is yes.  Any insights/answers given will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not the same but related and may be an interesting read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number

Comment: Ah, more related but still not the same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $C$ is closed under multiplication, it is helpful to know that $R_a$ is exactly the orbit of $a$ under the Galois group $G=Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$.  So, suppose $a,b\in C$ and let $c\in R_{ab}$.  Then $c=g(ab)=g(a)g(b)$ for some $g\in G$.  Since $a,b\in C$, we have $|g(a)|\geq|a|$ and $|g(b)|\geq |b|$ and so $|c|\geq |a||b|=|ab|$.

Comment: Thank you!  I agree with your answer to my first question, however, I realized I did not quite ask what I was looking for so I edited my original question.  I found your comment about the orbit particularly helpful! As far as your answer to my second question(which is the same) I agree with your result as long as both a,b are in the Gal(f_ab), however, if either one of them is not, then we can no longer say g(ab)=g(a)g(b).  Am I thinking incorrectly or is there a way around this?  Again, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: That's why I used the Galois group of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.  (Or, any Galois extension that contains both $a$ and $b$ would work.)